# SQL Server datetime ranges between records

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

What would be the best way to get datetime ranges between records in SQL Server? I think it would be easiest to explain with an example.

I have the following data - these records start and end datetime ranges would never overlap:

| ID | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/27/2021 06:00:00 | 1/27/2021 09:00:00 |
| 2 | 1/27/2021 10:00:00 | 1/27/2021 14:00:00 |
| 3 | 1/27/2021 21:00:00 | 1/28/2021 04:00:00 |
| 4 | 1/28/2021 06:00:00 | 1/28/2021 09:00:00 |

I need to get the date time range between records. So the resulting SQL query would return the following result set (ID doesn't matter):

| ID | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/27/2021 09:00:00 | 1/27/2021 10:00:00 |
| 2 | 1/27/2021 14:00:00 | 1/27/2021 21:00:00 |
| 3 | 1/28/2021 04:00:00 | 1/28/2021 06:00:00 |

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select id, end as start, lead(start) over (order by start) as end
      from t
     ) t
where end is not null;
```

Note:  `end` is a lousy name for a column, given that it is a SQL keyword.  I assume it is for illustrative purposes only.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b3faa/3) is a SQL Fiddle.